# Including only the calling file

Tags: input, include

I'm currently writing a large document with many included files.
I'm using the command `% !TEX root = main.tex` at the beginning of the included files, as in the following example:

`subfile1.tex`:

```
% !TEX root = main.tex
\section{Algebra}
(...)
```

`subfile2.tex`:

```
% !TEX root = main.tex
\section{Analysis}
(...)
```

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\include{subfile1.tex}
\include{subfile2.tex}
\end{document}
```

**I would like to compile only the content of `subfile1.tex`, `subfile2.tex` when editing these files.**

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell to the master document to compile only the calling document, via a command similar to `% !TEX root = main.tex`.

Ideally, I'm looking for commands such as

```
% !TEX \def\compileOnlyOneFile{YES}
% !TEX \def\nameFile{CURRENT_FILE}
```

PS: I'm using `TeXShop` on macOS.

Comment: Since you are using `\include` I would suggest that you look up what the `\includeonly` command does.

Comment: Thanks @daleif. I know `\includeonly` but I would like to be able to compile `subfile1`, `subfile2`, without modifying `main.tex`.

Comment: Then you should use a different approach. I see no issues in altering `\includeonly` in `main.tex`, it is simple and the editors understand it. The rest is just making things more complicated for yourself (and those who makes the editors)

Comment: Then imagine I have hundreds of `subfiles` and I am compiling several of them at the same time.

Comment: In that case I would make a different build system that are not dependent on the editor. Problably more in line with being able to compile each subfile on its own. Note that no matter what you do here, you still need the `\includeonly` mechanish if you want section numbers etc to be consistent on a limited compilation.

Comment: if you are processing multiple subfiles at the same time and want to generate separate pdf you don't want to set root to `main.tex` as that will mean they all make main.pdf and over-write. give each subfile its own mainfile eg subfile one has root subfile1-main where subfile1-main is  just `\includeonly{subfile1}\input {main}`

Comment: In your example you use the book-class but you don't have `\chapter`. Sections will be numbered 0.1  0.2  0.3 etc.   I mention this because one needs to know in which way your file-structure resembles the sectioning-structure of your document.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. I already thought of this solution but I don't want to create so many `subfile-...main.tex` files. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a file **jobnameredirector.tex** which checks

- whether the `\documentclass`-command was already used and therefore redefined equal to the macro `\@twoclasseserror` and
- whether `\begin{document}` was already processed and therefore `\AtBeginDocument` is redefined equal to `\@onlypreamble`

and performs appropriate actions in these different situations.

Via `\input` load that file **jobnameredirector.tex** in the preamble of your **main.tex** and right at the beginnings of your subfiles.

In case of being "inside the preamble" the command `\@include` can be patched to ensure that when reading sub-.aux-files takes place, with hyperref being loaded the circumstance is taken into account that destinations coming from other sub-files need to be redirected to the **main.pdf** where they exist.

In case of being "before the preamble" `\jobname` can be redirected and the real underlying mechanism for including the URL of **main.pdf** with cross-references coming from other sub-files can be defined.

This way compiling

- **main.tex** yields a .pdf-file **main.pdf** where everything is `\include`d, and thus containing everything. You also get **main.log** and **main.aux** and **main.toc** and **main.lof** and **main.lot** etc.
- **subfile1.tex** yields a .pdf-file **subfile1.pdf** containing everything from **main.tex** whereby all `\include`-commands but the `\include`-command for **subfile1.tex** are ignored. Additionally you get **subfile1.log** and **main.aux** and **main.toc** and **main.lof** and **main.lot** etc.
- **subfile2.tex** yields a .pdf-file **subfile2.pdf** containing everything from **main.tex** whereby all `\include`-commands but the `\include`-command for **subfile2.tex** are ignored. Additionally you get **subfile2.log** and **main.aux** and **main.toc** and **main.lof** and **main.lot** etc.

If you want cross-references from one file to another to work out, **main.tex** must have been compiled, whereby all files were included and thus all partial .aux-files **subfile1.aux**, **subfile2.aux** etc were created.

If the hyperref-package is loaded, hyperlinks created due to cross-referencing-commands and directing to destinations that in **main.pdf** come into being due to `\include`ing sub-files other than the one currently compiled and therefore not available within the .pdf-file resulting from the current compilation are directed to **main.pdf**, assuming that **main.pdf** and all **subfile.pdf** are in the same directory.
If this is not the case, within **jobnameredirector.tex** look up the line `\newcommand\URLofMainFile{./main.pdf}%` and change that definition so that it suits your directory-structure of .pdf-files.

Hyperlinks coming into being due to bookmarks and/or `\tableofcontents`/`\listoffigures`/`\listoftables` are not taken into account. Therefore when compiling sub-files you may still easily encounter warning-messages like

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{section.1.2} has been refer
enced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

No warranties. Try at your own risk.

**main.tex**

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%======================================================================
% In case of loading hyperref do this _after_ loading hyperref:
\input jobnameredirector.tex
%======================================================================

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter in main document}
\section{Section in main document}\label{main}

References: \ref{main}/\ref{Algebra}/\ref{Analysis}

\include{subfile1.tex}
\include{subfile2.tex}
\end{document}
```

**subfile1.tex**

```latex
\input jobnameredirector.tex
%======================================================================
\section{Algebra}\label{Algebra}
References: \ref{main}/\ref{Algebra}/\ref{Analysis}

(...)
```

**subfile2.tex**

```latex
\input jobnameredirector.tex
%======================================================================
\section{Analysis}\label{Analysis}
References: \ref{main}/\ref{Algebra}/\ref{Analysis}

(...)
```

**jobnameredirector.tex**

```latex
\edef\restoreat{\noexpand\catcode`\noexpand\@=\the\catcode`\@\relax}%
\makeatletter
\ifx\documentclass\@twoclasseserror
  % Document-Preamble / \documentclass has already been processed.
  \ifx\AtBeginDocument\@onlypreamble\else
    % \begin{document} is not reached yet.
%    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}\iftrue{\csname iffalse \endcsname}%
      \RequirePackage{etoolbox}%
      \providecommand\patchnewlabel[1]{}%
      \providecommand\resetnewlabel{}%
      \patchcmd{\@include}%
               {\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{#1.aux}}}%
               {%
                 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\patchnewlabel{#1}}%
                 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{#1.aux}}%
                 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\resetnewlabel}%
               }%
               {\message{Success with patching \string\include!!!}}%
               {\message{Problem patching \string\include!!!}}%
%    \fi
  \fi
  \restoreat
\else
  % Document-Preamble / \documentclass has not yet been processed:
  \@ifdefinable\savedjobname{\edef\savedjobname{\jobname}}%
  \def\jobname{main}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\jobname  \global\let\jobname=\jobname
  %=======================================================================
  \newcommand\URLofMainFile{./main.pdf}%
  \newcommand\patchnewlabel[1]{%
    \let\Saved@newl@bel=\@newl@bel
    \def\@newl@bel{\@newl@bel@addURL{#1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\@newl@bel@addURL[4]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{\savedjobname}=0 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\Saved@newl@bel{#2}{#3}{#4}}{\split@newl@bel@addURL#4{}{}{}\\{\Saved@newl@bel{#2}{#3}}}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\split@newl@bel@addURL{%
    \long\def\split@newl@bel@addURL#1#2#3#4#5\\#6{%
       \ifcat$\detokenize{#4}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
       {#6{{#1}{#2}}}%
       {%
         \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{%
            \romannumeral
            \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\URLofMainFile}}{0 {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
         }}{#6}%
       }%
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
  \newcommand\resetnewlabel{\let\@newl@bel=\Saved@newl@bel}%
  \newcommand\Saved@newl@bel{}%
  %=======================================================================
  \restoreat
  \includeonly{\savedjobname.tex}%
  \Exchange{\input{\jobname.tex}}%
\fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the root comment you can make the subfiles `\include` themselves via `\includeonly`

subfile1

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\jobname}{subfile1}=0
\AtBeginDocument{\includeonly{subfile1}}
\def\jobname{subfile1-main}
\def\tmp{\input{main}}
\expandafter\tmp
\fi
\section{Algebra}
(...)
```

subfile2

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\jobname}{subfile2}=0
\AtBeginDocument{\includeonly{subfile2}}
\def\jobname{subfile2-main}
\def\tmp{\input{main}}
\expandafter\tmp
\fi
\section{Analysis}
(...)
```

main

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\include{subfile1.tex}
\include{subfile2.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @UlrichDiez  that block is skipped completely on the second reading once main.tex is input. Although I suppose technically you are right about the `\endinput` it doesn't actually matter does it?, the file closes anyway.

Comment: @UlrichDiez since now you mentioned it I know someone will add \tracingifs=1 to get a warning I'll have to re-arrange to finish the if earlier :-)

Comment: Another problem might be hyperref's error-messages about missing destinations when compiling subfiles. :-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes sorry I'd updated the code without \endinput following your first comment

Comment: @UlrichDiez but then we can blame Ulrike so that's OK. (this is presumably only for drafts, since \includeonly makes the document start at section 0.2) so I don't think a few hyperref warnings would be too bad

Comment: Like you and some others, Ulrike represents an idol for me and therefore a priori is unblameable. :-)